# The analytical solution to a second order nonlinear ODE with sin(y) and cos(y)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, boundary-value-problem, analytic-functions, nonlinear-dynamics

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WsDA6.jpg)

I am trying to find the analytic solution or the approximate analytic solution of the bvp shown in the picture. I have solved it using several numerical methods beforehand. Hope you guys can help me!

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you type your questions (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.

Comment: Essentially, this is a pendulum equation $y''=-W^2\sin(y+F)$. While the solution can be expressed in a named function, this is not much more than giving a name to the solution.